# what is the shortcut to populate constructor variables in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, keyboard-shortcuts

I was watching a tutorial from pluralsight about asp.net MVC 5 framework And I saw something wonderful to speed up my coding. I googled it and i didn't find it. perhaps I didn't use right key words. any way, this is what i saw :

1- he was creating a constructor for Controller and the code was just like this :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
   {

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {

    }
```

and the cursor was on the word "context" , he used a shortcut  and sudnly in no time code became this :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context )
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

what shortcut he used to create properties like this ?
anyone knows how I can do this?

Comment: Any idea if there were other plugins involved?  [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for instance can do this in about 2 keystrokes

Comment: Probably Resharper. If I type a new constructor with a parameter, using Resharper I can click on the parameter name and press Alt+Enter (which is just the keystroke I assigned to this functionality) and I get a menu item called "Introduce and initialise field" which does this for me.

Comment: tutorials name is : " Build your own application frame work with asp.net MVC 5 " with Matt Honeycutt  from pluralsight , there is just MVC framework itself + StructureMap  and nothing else is involved and he is useing visualstudio 2013

Comment: Is there a small white circle in the bottom-right of the Visual Studio status bar? That indicates Resharper.

Comment: That tutorial is using Resharper.  You can see the Resharper menu at the top.  And if you start using Resharper you'll wonder how you ever coded without it.

Comment: thank you all ... so I'm abut to learn Resharper  ... thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is from ReSharper. It's the Introduce Field command. ReSharper is an excellent tool for productivity and consistency. See more information here about that feature of ReSharper: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Refactorings__Introduce_Field.html